# Can Humble Bundle V games be installed on ARM systems?

Tags: linux, humble-bundle

I know that all of the [Humble Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) games [can be installed](http://support.humblebundle.com/customer/portal/articles/559718-humble-indie-bundle-v-system-reqs) on Linux systems.

Is it possible to install and run them on my phone (a Samsung Galaxy Note), since I have a variant of Ubuntu (ARM-based) Linux installed?

The minimum system requirements does not specify any requirements regarding x86 or x64 (or ARM). I haven't tried it yet since I don't want to buy the games then find out that it's not compatible.

Answer (score 9):

The games are distributed in binary form (without source code), and it's almost certain that those binaries were compiled for x86 platforms. So no, the games won't run on your Galaxy Note.

(Even if they *were* distributed in source form, there's no guarantee that the code doesn't have any x86-specific parts in it.)

In addition, despite the operating system being the same, the *environment* on a Linux desktop system can be drastically different than that on a phone. The processor speed, graphics chipsets, and input methods are likely quite different.